# How to load N number of items from array at a time on button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, template-literals

I have an array of objects:

```
const resourcesData = [
  {
    title: 'Title 01',
    description: 'Description for Title 01',
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 02',
    description: 'Description for Title 02',
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 03',
    description: 'Description for Title 03',
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 04',
    description: 'Description for Title 04',
  },
  {
    title: 'Title 05',
    description: 'Description for Title 05',
  },
];
```

Currently using template literal to load them into the DOM:

```
function resourceTemplate(resource) {
  return `
    <div>
      <h2>${resource.title}</h2>
      <p>${resource.description}</p>
    </div>
  `;
}
```

```
function loadResources() {
  document.getElementById('resources').innerHTML = resourcesData
    .map(resourceTemplate)
    .join('');
}
```

It works when I load all of them at once.
How can I load only 2 at a time and only show the next 2 on button click?

So that it will show 2 items, click 'Load More' button and it will show the next 2 items.
Then when it reaches the end of the array, it will show only one and the load more button will be hidden.

---

*Update to what I tried as requested*
Previously I tried using a for loop to slice the result first like this:

```
console.log(resourcesData.length);
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < resourcesData.length; i += 2) {
  result = resourcesData.slice(i, i + 2);
  console.log(result);
}
```

I got 3 arrays back but I wasn't sure how to keep track which array to show on the button click.

Comment: What did you try to achieve that ?

Comment: I updated the question with what I tried to achieve the result thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to extract a certain number of elements from an Array:

```js
const resourcesData = [{"title":"Title 01","description":"Description for Title 01"},{"title":"Title 02","description":"Description for Title 02"},{"title":"Title 03","description":"Description for Title 03"},{"title":"Title 04","description":"Description for Title 04"},{"title":"Title 05","description":"Description for Title 05"}];

function resourceTemplate(resource) {
  return `
    <div>
      <h2>${resource.title}</h2>
      <p>${resource.description}</p>
    </div>
  `;
}

function loadResources() {
  document.getElementById('resources').innerHTML += resourcesData
    .splice(0, 2) // <-----------------------------------------------------
    .map(resourceTemplate)
    .join('');
    
  if (resourcesData.length === 0) { btn.style.display = 'none'; }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', loadResources);
```

```html
<div id="resources"></div>
<button id="btn">Load resources</button>
```

Comment: Is there a preference over [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox slice will just copy some elements of the array, with splice they are removed from the original array. so you don't need to track where you are, and just display elements [0] and [1] everytime. In the case you don't want to modify the original array slice will be the good option.

Comment: Yes, I assumed the OP did not care about keeping the elements in the Array. If he does, then we just need to keep an index to know where we are at and use slice, indeed